# Does a small partition with lot of re-writes on a small or large SDD make it wear out quickly?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, samsung-ssd

From my understanding, partitions are allocated based on the offsets. So it's location on drive is fixed.
So, Over an SSD, Does small partitions with lot of re-writes (say - swap partition on linux) cause a week point on the drive and let it wear out quickly.

Other way said, does SSD's wear-leveling work within a partition or across partitions i.e entire drive.

Comment: changed disk to drive :-)

Comment: Wear leveling is performed over the entire drive.  Partitions are a construct of software, and at the drive level, do not exist.  Your concern is unfounded.

Answer (score 2):

> So, Over an SSD, Does small partitions with lot of re-writes (say - swap partition on linux) cause a week point on the drive and let it wear out quickly.

No it won't wear out quicker just because the region the writes were done in was smaller because wear levelling works across the whole drive. See section [3.4 Wear levelling of Coding for SSDs](http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/). The physical region used for storing the data is distinct from the logical block address (LBA) that the OS writes and a mapping (the Flash Translation Layer) is kept of logical blocks to physical addresses by the SSD itself.